# Count unique instances in rows between two columns given by index

Tags: r, indexing

Hi I have an example data frame as follows. What I would like to do is count the number of instances of a unique value (example 1) that occur between the columns given by the indices ind1 and ind2. Output would be a vector with a number for each row that is the number of instances for that row.

```
COL1 <- c(1,1,1,NA,1,1)
COL2 <- c(1,NA,NA,1,1,1)
COL3 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1)
ind1 <- c(1,2,1,2,1,2)
ind2 <- c(3,3,2,3,3,3)
Data <- data.frame (COL1, COL2, COL3, ind1, ind2)
Data
COL1 COL2 COL3 ind1 ind2
1    1    1    1    3    
1    NA   1    2    3
1    NA   1    1    2   
NA   1    1    2    3
1    1    1    1    3
1    1    1    2    3
```

so example output should look like

```
3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2
```

My actual data set has many rows so I want to avoid loops as much as possible to save time. I was thinking an apply function with a sum(which(x==1)) may work I'm just not sure how to get the column values from the given indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to loop over the rows, extract the values based on the sequence index from 'ind1' to 'ind2' and get the count with `table`

```
apply(Data, 1, function(x) table(x[x['ind1']:x['ind2']]))
#[1] 3 1 1 2 3 2
```

Or using `sum`

```
apply(Data, 1, function(x) sum(x[x['ind1']:x['ind2']] == 1, na.rm = TRUE))
```

---

Or create a logical matrix and then use `rowSums`

```
rowSums(Data[1:3] * NA^!((col(Data[1:3]) >= Data$ind1) & 
       (col(Data[1:3]) <= Data$ind2)), na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 3 1 1 2 3 2
```

Comment: thank you. Both useful but i will most likely use apply since I can loop this into my other functions

Comment: Is there a way to change code to work within a loop where I have a list of dataframes that i want to add data$count column to where the 'ind1' and 'ind2' columns are named the same for each dataframe? I am running into a Na/NaN argument when I try to run this as   a function ```dataframe$count<- apply(dataframe, 1, function(x) sum(x[x['ind1']: x['ind2']] == 1, na.rm= TRUE))``` and then use lapply to loop through my list of dataframes. In some of the dataframes the ind 2 occurs before ind 1. I thought the na.rm would deal with this problem but maybe I am indexing the argument wrong?

Comment: In that case, just do `lapply(lst1, function(Data) {Data$count <- apply(Data, 1, function(x) table(x[x['ind1']:x['ind2']])); Data})`

Comment: sorry yah I did actually use lapply as you suggested, I just wrote the function seperate but I am still getting an error Error in x["ind1"]:x["ind2"]: Na/NaN argument. Traceback is just showing the source as being the function so I'm not sure why this is happening.

Comment: @JamieVarney Could it be that you have `NA` elements in the column that shows the erorr i.e. `NA:5#
Error in NA:5 : NA/NaN argument`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, yah one of my previous functions to replace NA was not running as expected so that fixed the issue!